# How can I tell if a dataframe is of mixed type?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to assign values to the diagonal of a dataframe.  The fastest way I can think of is to use numpy's `np.diag_indices` and do a slice assignment on the `values` array.  However, the values array is only a view and ready to accept assignment when a dataframe is of a single `dtype`

Consider the dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 1, 1], B=[1., 1., 1.], C=[1, 1, 1]))
```

---

```
d1

   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  1  0
```

---

```
d2

   A    B  C
0  1  1.0  1
1  1  1.0  1
2  1  1.0  1
```

Then let's get our indices

```
i, j = np.diag_indices(3)
```

`d1` is of a single `dtype` and therefore, this works

```
d1.values[i, j] = 0
d1

   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  1  0
```

But not on `d2`

```
d2.values[i, j] = 0
d2

   A    B  C
0  1  1.0  1
1  1  1.0  1
2  1  1.0  1
```

---

I need to write a function and make it fail when `df` is of mixed `dtype`.  How do I test that it is?  Should I trust that if it is, this assignment via the view will always work?

Comment: You inspect `d1.dtypes` which is a `Series` itself, and you check if all have the same value.

Comment: You mean `d2.dtypes.nunique()>1`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use internal `_is_mixed_type` method

```
In [3600]: d2._is_mixed_type
Out[3600]: True

In [3601]: d1._is_mixed_type
Out[3601]: False
```

Or, check unique `dtypes`

```
In [3602]: d1.dtypes.nunique()>1
Out[3602]: False

In [3603]: d2.dtypes.nunique()>1
Out[3603]: True
```

---

A bit of de-tour, `is_mixed_type` checks how `blocks` are consolidated.

```
In [3618]: len(d1.blocks)>1
Out[3618]: False

In [3619]: len(d2.blocks)>1
Out[3619]: True

In [3620]: d1.blocks    # same as d1.as_blocks()
Out[3620]:
{'int32':    A  B  C
 0  0  1  1
 1  1  0  1
 2  1  1  0}

In [3621]: d2.blocks
Out[3621]:
{'float64':      B
 0  1.0
 1  1.0
 2  1.0, 'int64':    A  C
 0  1  1
 1  1  1
 2  1  1}
```

Comment: I have seen this so many times in the source code :) though couldnt come up with this answer +1

Comment: I'm trying to use the method is_mixed_type, but it says it's not defined. Has this changed in more recent Python versions?

Answer (score 4):

```
def check_type(df):
  return len(set(df.dtypes)) == 1
```

or

```
 def check_type(df):
   return df.dtypes.nunique() == 1
```

Comment: A `set(..)` is never equal to 1. It can be equal to `{1}` (although not here). You probably want `len(set(df.dtypes))`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem should be len

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect `DataFrame.dtypes` to check the types of the columns. For instance:

```
>>> d1.dtypes
A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
dtype: object
>>> d2.dtypes
A      int64
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```

Given that there is **at least one column**, you can thus check this with:

```
np.all(d1.dtypes == d1.dtypes[0])
```

For your dataframes:

```
>>> np.all(d1.dtypes == d1.dtypes[0])
True
>>> np.all(d2.dtypes == d2.dtypes[0])
False
```

You can of course first check whether there is at least one column. So we can construct a function:

```
def all_columns_same_type(df):
    dtypes = df.dtypes
    return not dtypes.empty and np.all(dtypes == dtypes[0])
```